# Print C++ function name to C without decoration

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, function, dll

I am trying to build a DLL. I have been told to first print out the Function name using

```
../debug>dumpbin /exports demo.dll
```

The following is my C++ code

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void __cdecl Foo() {
return;
}
```

The following is my def file

```
LIBRARY 
EXPORTS
Foo
```

I want the function name to be printed as

```
ordinal hint RVA      name

      1    0 00011212 Foo = Foo
```

Instead I see:

```
ordinal hint RVA      name

      1    0 00011212 Foo = @ILT+525(Foo)
```

How can I disable the mangling/decoration?

I have seen questions where the solution was disabling "debug info" in linker. I don't want to do that. I am a newbie to C++ so not super knowledgeable. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: This isn't really a question about c++, but about some particular compiler.  What you are asking is outside the area that the c++ language specifies, so there is no general answer.  For every environment the answer may be different.

Comment: I'm afraid i can't do that, HAL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**There is no C++ name mangling going on here.** The function exported from the DLL is called `Foo`.

The `@ILT` syntax refers to a form of indirect call used in incremental linking (ILT stands for "Incremental Link Table" and the number identifies a slot in that table):

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/6cd9936a-c516-49e0-ba38-ed391669a69a/disassembly-operand-ilt?forum=vcgeneral

Comment: Thanks for the help! I disabled Incremental Linking in Visual Studio and it gave me "Foo"